# SharePoint Online AD Security Group Based Navigation Bar

Tags: sharepoint-online, security-trimming

I am trying to have group-based navigation in my SharePoint Online intranet. This is because I want only specific links to be in the dropdown of some menus to be visible to certain AD Security groups because of confidentiality.

I have read online about security trimming or client-side scripting, but in my site settings I am missing numerous options people mention in their guides but are not present.

In essense, I am curious in SharePoint Online how I can "censor" certain links in the main navigation bar based upon a users AD Security Group. Thanks

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM1G3.png)

Answer (score 0):

This feature isn't yet available in modern. See [Feature ID 34251](https://www.microsoft.com/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=SharePoint&searchterms=34251). Obviously the date is a bit off :-(

More information at [Target navigation, news, and files to specific audiences](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/target-navigation-news-and-files-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293).